# Submit form using JQuery won't append to list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I need to be able to append to a list (it's a leaderboard, but that's not relevant) by submitting through a form and appending to an ordered list using jquery. When I press submit nothing happens other than the button being pressed. Where am I going wrong?

HTML:

```
<main>
  <ol class="playerList">
    <li>Profit - 12,565</li>
    <li>carpe - 11,423</li>
    <li>Fate  -  11,003</li>
    <li>Fleta  -  10,931</li>
    <li>Fury  -  10,704</li>
    <li>Gesture  -  10,601</li>
    <li>Choihyobin  -  10,012</li>
    <li>MekO  -  9,879</li>
    <li>Birdring  -  9,850</li>
    <li>Mano  -  9,766</li>
  </ol>
</main>

<footer>
    <form id="submissionForm">
      <label id="nameLabel" for="pName"><u>Player name:</u></label>
      <input id="pName" type="text" placeholder="Enter player name...">
      <label for="pElims"><u>Elimination Count:</u></label>
      <input id="pElims" type="text" placeholder="Enter elimination count...">
      <input id="submitBtn" type="submit">
    </form>
</footer>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#submissionForm").on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    error = false;
    $(".error").hide();
    var playerName = $("#pName").var();
    var elimCount = $("#pElim").var();
    var newItem = (playerName + "  -  "+ elimCount);

    $('.playerList').append('<li>'+ newItem + '</li>');
    return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: Try looking at F12 console tab....does that help?  Specifically...what are you intending with  `$("#pName").var();` and `$("#pElim").var();` ?

Comment: So, I was looking to get #pName and #pElim and concatonate (think that’s the word?) into one string then add that string to my list. Going to try your suggestion of changing Var to Val when I’m home and I’ll let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.var()` is not a valid way to get an input element's value.
Also, the id on the elim count does not match the id on the HTML element.

```
var playerName = $("#pName").var();
var elimCount = $("#pElim").var();
```

It should be:

```
var playerName = $("#pName").val();
var elimCount = $("#pElims").val();
```

Comment: Completely right, thank you so much, was causing me such a headache!